# While loops forever

Tags: c++

Im trying to have the program prompt the user for a valid input after inputting something other than a positive number, but this code just makes it loop forever. How would i get it to ask the user to input a valid input again?

```
cout << "\tAmount on deposit: ";
cin >> deposit;
if (!deposit || deposit < 0){

    while (!deposit || deposit < 0)
    {
        cout << "\tPlease enter a positive number! " << endl;
        cout << setw(60) << "Amount on deposit: ";
        cin.ignore(deposit);
    }
}else ...
```

Comment: i was getting desperate and figured i'd try cin.ignore. Mind showing me the right way?

Comment: ah, i see it should be    if(!cin) not if(!deposit)

Comment: What's the type of `deposit`?

Comment: @TheeOomer What do you think `cin.ignore(deposit)` should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the header `<limits>` and use this code to get rid of those character inputs that you asked in the comment.

Change your code to

```
while ( deposit <= 0)
{                 
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max( ),'\n');
    cout << "\tPlease enter a positive number! " << endl;
    cout << setw(60) << "Amount on deposit: ";
    cin >> deposit; // take the input inside the while loop                    
}
```

The problem is that you are not changing the value of `deposit` inside your loop. In your code, the value of `deposit` does not change inside your while loop, which is causing the infinite loop.

Also, rather than `!deposit`, you can just change your condition to

```
while ( deposit <= 0)
```

Also, unless you really need it, I'd remove the if statement as well, as I don't see a use for it ( unless you have some specific reason for using it )

Comment: @TheeOomer ,Edited answer, see if this does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

take input within while loop(I am assuming other things and your logic is correct):

```
while ( deposit < 1)
{
    cout << "\tPlease enter a positive number! " << endl;
    cout << setw(60) << "Amount on deposit: ";
    cin.ignore(deposit);
    cin >> deposit;
}
```